# Implementation of one way dependancy property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am developing a custom User Control using WPF.
I have registered DependancyProperty but I want to make it only OneWay binding. Is it possible to do it?
Here is what I have:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomPrProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CustomPr",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(CustomView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnDependencyPropertyChanged));
```

This way when someone use the User Control, he can make it OneWay, OneWayToSource and TwoWay. How can I make it read only property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `BindsTwoWayByDefault` property of the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` to specify that the property binds two-way by default. The mode can still be changed by setting the `Mode` property of an individual binding to something else than `TwoWay`.

To create a read-only dependency property that cannot be set, you should use the [RegisterReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerreadonly?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads) method:

```
internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey CustomPrKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
 "CustomPr",
 typeof(string),
 typeof(CustomView),
 new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
);

public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomPrProperty = CustomPrKey.DependencyProperty;

public string CustomPr
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(CustomPrProperty); }
}
```

Comment: @ mm8, Hi, My custom DP is set used default TwoWay binding, but when I set with mode=OneWay in Xaml, nothing happens when I Change binding property value. Can DP use as that way?